# Prove a sequentially compact metric space is bounded.

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, functional-analysis, limits, metric-spaces

Prove that if the metric space $(X, d)$ is sequentially compact, that there exists points $x_0$ and $y_0$ belonging to $X$ such that;

$$d(x, y) \leq d(x_0, y_0)$$ for every $x$ and $y$ belonging to $X$.

I can see that we will need to use sequences with $x_0$ and $y_0$ as limits but I'm not sure how to prove this for all cases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is not bounded. Fix $x\in X.$

Claim: The collection of $d(x,y),~y\in X$ is not bounded. If it were bounded by some $C,$ then for any $y,z\in X$ we would have

\begin{equation*}
d(y,z)\leq d(y,x)+d(x,z)\leq 2C
\end{equation*}

which is a contradiction. Since the definition of sequential compactness needs every infinite sequence to have a convergent subsequence, pick $x_n\in X,~d(x,x_n)>n.$ The resulting sequene is not Cauchy since for any $n,$ the set $d(x_m,x_n)$ for $m$ is not bounded. Therefore, $\exists m>n$ such that $d(x_m,x_n)>1.$

Comment: Fantastic. Is it enough to just point out that clearly there is no convergent subsequence for our defined sequence?